# user.displayName is showing undefined NextJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

*Jumping directly into the question,* when I do `console.log(user);` it is returning me an object in which the `displayName` has a value that is a string. But when I do `console.log(user.displayName);`, it should give me the value *Agrim Singh (<-- I've entered this value).* But it threw an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')

*Here is an image of the error:*
[image]

*Also, I'm using NextJS with Firebase.*

*Here is the code of the file `[postid].jsx`:*

```
const post = ({ post, user }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [addComment, setAddComment] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();
  const { postid } = router.query;

  console.log(user); // <--- Working perfectly.
  console.log(user.displayName); // <--- Throwing error.

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!addComment || !name) {
      alert("Please fill all the fields proplerly!");
    } else {
      db.collection("posts").doc(postid).collection("comments").add({
        name: name, // <--- Please ignore this line for now
        comment: addComment,
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="post container text-center">
      <h2>{post.title}</h2>
      <h5>Created On - {new Date(post.createdAt).toDateString()}</h5>
      <br />
      <img src={post.imageUrl} alt={post.alt} />
      <br />
      <p>{post.description}</p>
      <br />
      <form>
        <div className="form-input">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            className="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter Your Name"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-input">
          <textarea
            name="add-comment"
            id="add-comment"
            className="add-comment"
            value={addComment}
            onChange={(e) => setAddComment(e.target.value)}
            cols="100"
            rows="3"
            placeholder="Add your Comment"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="btn-warning">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>

      <div className="comments">
        <p className="comment">
          <b>
            <i>Name</i>:
          </b>{" "}
          <span>Comment</span> {/* <--- I've not programmed this line because of the error. */}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default post;

export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  const result = await db.collection("posts").doc(params.postid).get();
  return {
    props: {
      post: {
        ...result.data(),
        createdAt: result.data().createdAt.toMillis(),
      },
    },
  };
}
```

I've passed the `user` prop to all files in the file `_app.js`.

Here is the code:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="banner-div">
        <Navbar user={user} />
        <img src="/banner.jpg" alt="School Banner" className="banner" />
      </div>
      <Component {...pageProps} user={user} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Edit:*** `user.displayName` is working everywhere except the `[postid].jsx` file.

***Edit 2:*** When I did

```
console.log(user);
```

It is showing both null and the object.

Here is the image:[image]

Comment: could you show the output from the terminal as well? I am guessing the function got called multiple time in here.

Comment: You literally initialise the `user` state to `null` so why would you be surprised that it is `null` at times?

Comment: @Philisonstrike If the `user` is logged out, then the user will be set to `null`. But on the website, I'm logged in. Well, I'll try this one. *Edit:* Yup. Still showing undefined.

Comment: Are you getting this error on loading the app, or visiting `post/:postId` page?

Comment: @AnindyaDey when I visit the `[postid].jsx` file

Comment: In the `[postid].jsx`, as you are using `getServerSideProps` method, the props you're sending back would override the props passed to the page component. Could you debug around that? Also, could you console log everything that is being injected to getServerSideProps? If you see "user", then pass it back along with "post".

Comment: @AnindyaDey *There is one more thing*. When I did `console.log(userData);` it is showing both null and the object. And both are coming from the same line. I've also added this to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Now it's working!***

I did this

```
const userData = user; // <--- "user" is the prop I called from the file "_app.js"
console.log(userData?.displayName);
```

In the console, it is showing the value.

Adding ***`?`*** made all things work.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?